# Javascript Output Variable Html

Tags: javascript, html

I have this:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
<div style="min-height: 300px;" class="custom-order-form">
    <p class="fieldset-title">Preenche!</p>

    <div class="form_fields">
        <label for="weight">Peso (KG)</label>
        <label for="level" style="padding-left:30px">Nível de Surf</label>

        <br />
        <input type="text" name="weight" id="weight">
        <select name="level" id="level">
                <option value="+10">Iniciado</option>
                <option value="0">Intermedio</option>
                <option value="-6">Avançado</option>
            </select>
    </div>
```

And now i need ti text the "level" final value, how i can do that?
Thanks

Comment: Why *php* tag? Neither the code nor the question is related to PHP.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)